# Cordova ios plugins Failed after build complete when app loading in xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, sap-smp

Loading XCodewe are getting this error.

Any solution?

> FAILED pluginJSON =
>   ["AuthProxy1342781311","AuthProxy","initWebStrategies",[]] 2020-01-24
>   12:59:00.432213+0530 myJobCard[23188:330651] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar'
>   not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in
>   config.xml. 2020-01-24 12:59:00.432347+0530 myJobCard[23188:330651]
>
> FAILED pluginJSON = ["StatusBar1342781312","StatusBar","_ready",[]]
>   2020-01-24 12:59:00.432539+0530 myJobCard[23188:330651] ERROR: Plugin
>   'Console' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping
>   in config.xml. 2020-01-24 12:59:00.432642+0530 myJobCard[23188:330651]
>
> FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","Console","logLevel",["LOG","Set
>   javascript initial log level: ERROR"]] 2020-01-24 12:59:00.432821+0530
>   myJobCard[23188:330651] ERROR: Plugin 'Console' not found, or is not a
>   CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml. 2020-01-24
>   12:59:00.432906+0530 myJobCard[23188:330651]
>
> FAILED pluginJSON =
>   ["INVALID","Console","logLevel",["LOG","Ionic Native:  event fired
>   after 444 ms"]] 2020-01-24 12:59:00.433063+0530
>   myJobCard[23188:330651] ERROR: Plugin 'SMPSettingsExchangePlugin' not
>   found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
>   We are using the following versions in npm:
>   [version image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R20mz.png)

List of plugins which we are using in our project:[List of plugin verions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h877k.png)

We are trying the following solutions:

1. In X-Code, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file that should be in your Plugins directory (but is missing from the compiled sources).All ready.M file is available . please follow the image in x-code [All plugins .m files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0ywN.png)
2. In short:

   1. delete ./plugins/ios.json,
   2. then delete ./platforms/ios,
   3. then run cordova platform add ios
   4. then cordova build. Deleting ios.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say that you aren't providing a lot of information, which makes guessing a lot harder - what app are you trying to build? Is the SMP SDK installed? It does look a little to me that the project config is out of sync with the sources, which may happen if you blindly delete folders in Cordova :)

To be safe when Cordova runs into hiccups, I usually

1. Remove the offending plugins with `cordova plugin remove <id>`
2. Remove the offending platform with `cordova platform add <ios>`
3. In case of doubt, get rid of the `plugins` and `platforms` folders altogether
4. Re-add the offending platform via `cordova platform add ios`
5. Re-add the offending plugin via `cordova plugin add <id>`

Also, as a general rule of thumb - do not mess with the `platforms` folder. As opposed to Ionic sources, the generated output is not meant to be modified, and if there are issues with the output, it is likely that there are issues with your Cordova project settings.

Maybe my CI tutorial gives you another hint or two as well: https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/ci-best-practices-mobile-cordova.html

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for giving replay.